# Cross-compilation fails during `help` installation: "installing Rd objects failed"

Tags: r, cross-compiling, conda-build, conda-forge

### Installation self-loads library during `help` step

I've encountered an issue when cross-compiling [the R package `xml2`](https://github.com/r-lib/xml2) on the Conda Forge infrastructure ([r-xml2-feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/r-xml2-feedstock/pull/23)). The Conda Forge *nix builds for R execute with:

```
R CMD INSTALL --no-test-load --build .
```

where the `--no-test-load` flag (normally) helps avoid any issues with cross-compilation. The building of the dynamic library, including linking to a target-native `libxml2`, works fine. However, the package installation fails during the `help` step:

```bash
* installing *source* package ‘xml2’ ...
** package ‘xml2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Found INCLUDE_DIR and/or LIB_DIR!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I$PREFIX/include/libxml2 
Using PKG_LIBS=-L$PREFIX/lib -lxml2
** libs
arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"$BUILD_PREFIX/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I$PREFIX/include/libxml2  -DUCHAR_TYPE=wchar_t -DU_SHOW_CPLUSPLUS_API=0  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem $PREFIX/include -mmacosx-version-min=11.0 -I$PREFIX/include   -fPIC  -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -isystem $PREFIX/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1648746613541/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.5 -fdebug-prefix-map=$PREFIX=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c connection.cpp -o connection.o
arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang -I"$BUILD_PREFIX/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I$PREFIX/include/libxml2  -DUCHAR_TYPE=wchar_t -DU_SHOW_CPLUSPLUS_API=0  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem $PREFIX/include -mmacosx-version-min=11.0 -I$PREFIX/include   -fPIC  -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem $PREFIX/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1648746613541/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.5 -fdebug-prefix-map=$PREFIX=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c init.c -o init.o
arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"$BUILD_PREFIX/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I$PREFIX/include/libxml2  -DUCHAR_TYPE=wchar_t -DU_SHOW_CPLUSPLUS_API=0  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem $PREFIX/include -mmacosx-version-min=11.0 -I$PREFIX/include   -fPIC  -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -isystem $PREFIX/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1648746613541/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.5 -fdebug-prefix-map=$PREFIX=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c xml2_doc.cpp -o xml2_doc.o
arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"$BUILD_PREFIX/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I$PREFIX/include/libxml2  -DUCHAR_TYPE=wchar_t -DU_SHOW_CPLUSPLUS_API=0  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem $PREFIX/include -mmacosx-version-min=11.0 -I$PREFIX/include   -fPIC  -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -isystem $PREFIX/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1648746613541/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.5 -fdebug-prefix-map=$PREFIX=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c xml2_init.cpp -o xml2_init.o
arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"$BUILD_PREFIX/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I$PREFIX/include/libxml2  -DUCHAR_TYPE=wchar_t -DU_SHOW_CPLUSPLUS_API=0  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem $PREFIX/include -mmacosx-version-min=11.0 -I$PREFIX/include   -fPIC  -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -isystem $PREFIX/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1648746613541/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.5 -fdebug-prefix-map=$PREFIX=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c xml2_namespace.cpp -o xml2_namespace.o
arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"$BUILD_PREFIX/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I$PREFIX/include/libxml2  -DUCHAR_TYPE=wchar_t -DU_SHOW_CPLUSPLUS_API=0  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem $PREFIX/include -mmacosx-version-min=11.0 -I$PREFIX/include   -fPIC  -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -isystem $PREFIX/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1648746613541/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.5 -fdebug-prefix-map=$PREFIX=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c xml2_node.cpp -o xml2_node.o
arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"$BUILD_PREFIX/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I$PREFIX/include/libxml2  -DUCHAR_TYPE=wchar_t -DU_SHOW_CPLUSPLUS_API=0  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem $PREFIX/include -mmacosx-version-min=11.0 -I$PREFIX/include   -fPIC  -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -isystem $PREFIX/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1648746613541/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.5 -fdebug-prefix-map=$PREFIX=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c xml2_output.cpp -o xml2_output.o
arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"$BUILD_PREFIX/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I$PREFIX/include/libxml2  -DUCHAR_TYPE=wchar_t -DU_SHOW_CPLUSPLUS_API=0  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem $PREFIX/include -mmacosx-version-min=11.0 -I$PREFIX/include   -fPIC  -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -isystem $PREFIX/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1648746613541/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.5 -fdebug-prefix-map=$PREFIX=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c xml2_schema.cpp -o xml2_schema.o
arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"$BUILD_PREFIX/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I$PREFIX/include/libxml2  -DUCHAR_TYPE=wchar_t -DU_SHOW_CPLUSPLUS_API=0  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem $PREFIX/include -mmacosx-version-min=11.0 -I$PREFIX/include   -fPIC  -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -isystem $PREFIX/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1648746613541/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.5 -fdebug-prefix-map=$PREFIX=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c xml2_url.cpp -o xml2_url.o
arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"$BUILD_PREFIX/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -I$PREFIX/include/libxml2  -DUCHAR_TYPE=wchar_t -DU_SHOW_CPLUSPLUS_API=0  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem $PREFIX/include -mmacosx-version-min=11.0 -I$PREFIX/include   -fPIC  -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -isystem $PREFIX/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1648746613541/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.5 -fdebug-prefix-map=$PREFIX=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c xml2_xpath.cpp -o xml2_xpath.o
arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L$PREFIX/lib/R/lib -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,$PREFIX/lib -L$PREFIX/lib -o xml2.dylib connection.o init.o xml2_doc.o xml2_init.o xml2_namespace.o xml2_node.o xml2_output.o xml2_schema.o xml2_url.o xml2_xpath.o -L$PREFIX/lib -lxml2 -L$PREFIX/lib/R/lib -lR -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable
installing to /Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-xml2_1649126088207/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/lib/R/library/00LOCK-work/00new/xml2/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
Error :  unable to load shared object '/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-xml2_1649126088207/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/lib/R/library/00LOCK-work/00new/xml2/libs/xml2.dylib':
  dlopen(/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-xml2_1649126088207/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/lib/R/library/00LOCK-work/00new/xml2/libs/xml2.dylib, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-xml2_1649126088207/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/lib/R/library/00LOCK-work/00new/xml2/libs/
ERROR: installing Rd objects failed for package ‘xml2’
```

Obviously, this fails because the `.dylib` is not compiled for the host architecture, so we wouldn't expect it to be loadable. The question is: **Why is the `help` installation step attempting to load the shared library? and how can this be avoided?**

---

### What I've tried

I've confirmed that it really is just the `help` step that triggers this self-loading. The package build works just fine with addition of a `--no-help` flag. However, this is not ideal - it would be preferable to deliver help manuals to all platforms.

Attempting to exclude only specific parts of the help did not avoid the self-loading error, namely, each of the `--no-docs` and `--no-html` flags alone still failed.

### Thoughts

I suspect something in the .Rd files (examples?) is triggering R to attempt to load the library. However, I've not encountered this issue with other R packages that use Roxygen2-generated .Rd files as help documentation. For example, `nloptr` ([package](https://github.com/astamm/nloptr), [feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/r-nloptr-feedstock)) cross-compiles successfully. Any insights into what to look for would be appreciated.

---

### Additional Details

- Build Platform: **osx-64**
- Target Platform: **osx-arm64**
- R versions: 4.0 and 4.1

Comment: I feel asking/crosslinking in conda-forge gitter has the highest chance to give you leads: https://gitter.im/conda-forge/conda-forge.github.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some packages need to import itself when building the docs.
In the case of xml2, the xml options are loaded from the R package
and then injected to the docs. See
https://github.com/r-lib/xml2/blob/ab2078976c9ab57116c7c9175632e7d19d45273f/man/read_xml.Rd#L58

To fix this, you'll have to compile the package twice.
One for cross architecture (Apple Silicon) and one for
native architecture (Intel) and use the native package
to build the docs assuming that the docs generated are
the same for both architecture. There might an example or
two in conda-forge that does this.